# Flutter Google Maps

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I **restrict** orders outside my country being proceeded ?
Since I am new to flutter, I might have missed some resources online. In case if anyone has any resources plz mention it. Thank You

Comment: May be [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) is something you want to check out

Answer (score 0):

For restricting orders outside of your country you just need to check the country in which your user is and for that in flutter there is a package [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) which you can use to find the location of user and then just check if it matches with your country.